# F#- Getting error HttpFs.Client : "code":"415","message":"Content type '' not supported"

Tags: f#

I am using F# library HttpFs.Client for API Testing. I know that I am doing something wrong by not setting the correct content type in Headers but I don't know how to set it.

[]
let `Play with Rest API`() =

```
let request = Request.createUrl Post "https://c2c-lms-qa.ninja24.in/login"
               |> Request.setHeader (Accept "application/json")
               |> Request.bodyString ReadFile //Reading content of json body
               |> Request.responseAsString
               |> run

printfn "Here's the Response is : %s" request
```

In this case, I keep getting an error: {"code":"415","message":"Content type '' not supported","errors":[{"field":null,"message":"Content type '' not supported","rejectedValue":null}]}Here's the Response is : {"code":"415","message":"Content type '' not supported","errors":[{"field":null,"message":"Content type '' not supported","rejectedValue":null}]}

I tried various other ways like bypassing these:
a) |> Request.setHeader (ContentType "application/json")

Showing an error: This expression was expected to have type    'ContentType'    but here has type    'string' 
Or

b) |> Request.setHeader (Custom("Content-Type", "application/json"))

System.Exception : Exception raised by job
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.Result message:

JSON body:
{
  "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCINCwiZXhwIwQHWsiA8A-mm9jZ33VM3BGeBW9CsJmaeZ4P4uTTQ13PKEboXLu7Heik4UNUfyL1xHvjVVPuIiz--gzzXGN76-ReJ5jHoG_l0JauKbJpgap-HE43JqF08c7zBuHFUp9DmjyNlcbZra7TJsMKPVE7oCYPSpbhCRYLyzlms5xBFO5aqL-IPEOnXJbLkXA",
  "type": "GOOGLE_LOGIN"
}

Note* As suggested, I have tried by removing content-type param itself like:

let `Play with Rest API`() =  
printfn "Body File content is : %s" ReadFile  
let request = Request.createUrl Post "https://c2c-lms-qa.ninja24.in/login”                    |> Request.bodyString ReadFile 
|> Request.responseAsString 
|> run

printfn "Here's the Response is : %s" request

But I am still getting this error: Here's the Response is : {"code":"415","message":"Content type '' not supported","errors":[{"field":null,"message":"Content type '' not supported","rejectedValue":null}]}

To Repro on postman, you can use this data:
POST URl: https://c2c-lms-qa.ninja24.in/login
Body: {"idToken":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiKNMULubJGpLSGP4Rjsibf9sQGIFy3cnb46wsn0-L03vNu9LuZidwZ30ZiZ28Jua3jQha__yjmdnqaBrkdSybjz1jOsQ4IwQHWsiA8A-mm9jZ33VM3BGeBW9CsJmaeZ4P4uTTQ13PKEboXLu7Heik4UNUfyL1xHvjVVPuIiz--gzzXGN76-ReJ5jHoG_l0JauKbJpgap-HE43JqF08c7zBuHFUp9DmjyNlcbZra7TJsMKPVE7oCYPSpbhCRYLyzlms5xBFO5aqL-IPEOnXJbLkXA","type":"GOOGLE_LOGIN"}

As I have provided invalid token, you'll see this expected response in Postman:
{
    "code": "401",
    "message": "Invalid Token",
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": null,
            "message": "Invalid Token",
            "rejectedValue": null
        }
    ]
}

But on F# library HttpFs.Client, I get this:
{"code":"415","message":"Content type '' not supported","errors":[{"field":null,"message":"Content type '' not supported","rejectedValue":null}]}

Comment: This is unrelated to F#, your api does not support the content header your passing by.  Have you tried removing the content header alltogether.

Comment: @KoenigLear- Yes, i tried like:

Comment: @KoenigLear- Thanks for checking. I have updated my comments where I have tried without content header as you suggested but it's still not working. If possible, please try with the data I provided above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should fix it.  The syntax to pass the content type is a bit akward:

```
Request.createUrl Post "https://c2c-lms-qa.ninja24.in/login"
|> Request.setHeader (ContentType (ContentType.create("application", "json")))
|> Request.bodyString token //Reading content of json body
|> Request.responseAsString
|> run
```

Comment: - Thank you so much. I did try it with ContentType (ContentType.create("application/json")) earlier but not ContentType (ContentType.create("application", "json"))         Thanks once again.